# The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) from the type FluentWait<WebDriver> refers to the missing type Function

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am using examples from
 http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp
for testing but getting this error 
The method until(Function) from the type FluentWait refers to the missing type Function

code is attached with error in screenshot.
I have searched everywhere but found no solution.
[Code image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvhsN.png)

Comment: `java.util.function.Function` was added in Java 8 - are you using Java 8?

Comment: i was using java 7. It works now . Thanks @greg-449